# Negative Fractional Indices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I figure this out:

$$\frac{27^{-2/3}}{16^{3/4}}$$

Please show workings. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what a fractional  power means? It means taking a root. So $16^\frac{1}{4}$ would be $2$, because $2^4=16$. Can you use this logic to your benefit?

Comment: Ah so it would be -2(3)/3(2) after that step to both sides, meaning -6/6 equalling -1. Thanks so much!!

Comment: You've figured out the secret, but there's a mistake in your calculation. You will get $\frac{3^{-2}}{2^3}$, which will give you $\frac{1}{3^22^3}$, which gives you $\frac{1}{72}$.

Comment: Although you seem to refuse to use MathJax (e.g. from your other questions), I strongly suggest to format your questions and comments (note that your comments cannot be edited by others). May be then you could avoid such errors like writing
$3^{-2}/2^3$ as $-2(3)/3(2) = -6/6 = -1.$

Comment: @gammatester Not exactly the best with MathJax, also I had thought that it was supposed to be multiplied not raised to the power with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so first we can see that both 27 and 16 can be written as powers of 3 and 2 respectively, so the expression in your question becomes $$\frac{(3^3)^{-\frac{2}{3}}}{(2^4)^{\frac{3}{4}}}$$ Next, we need to use a few index laws to simplify this. Remember that $(a^m)^n = a^{mn}$ and that $a^{-m} = \frac{1}{a^m}$. From this, we can simplify the above expression $$\frac{(3^3)^{-\frac{2}{3}}}{(2^4)^{\frac{3}{4}}} = \frac{3^{-2}}{2^{3}} = \frac{1}{3^22^3}=\frac{1}{72}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$27^{-2/3} = \frac{1}{27^{2/3}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{27^2}}$$ and
$$16^{3/4} = \sqrt[4]{16^3}$$

Comment: Somehow I feel $\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[3]{27}}\right)^2$ and $\left(\sqrt[4]{16}\right)^3$ would be easier to do in my head

Comment: @Henry It's true too, your expression is a bit more developed.

Answer (score 1):

it is
 $$\frac{1}{16^{3/4}\cdot27^{2/3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{16^3}\cdot\sqrt[3]{27^2}}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2^{12}}\sqrt[3]{3^6}}=\frac{1}{2^33^2}=\frac{1}{8\cdot9}=\frac{1}{72}$$

Comment: The $8$ should be in the denominator

Comment: what do you meant?

Comment: You have misread the question.

Comment: yes or the question was just edited!

Comment: Perhaps it _was_ re-edited within the grace period. The source of the OP's original version does not have a negative exponent on 16.

Comment: i have edited my answer thank you for the $-2$

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I shall upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Fractional exponents

$$27^{-2/3} = \frac{1}{27^{2/3}}$$

That is the first step, because you firstly have to remove the minus sign.

Now the fractional part:

$$27^{2/3} = \sqrt[3]{27^2}$$

Hence

$$\frac{27^{-2/3}}{16^{3/4}} = \frac{1}{27^{2/3} 16^{3/4}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{27^2} \sqrt[4]{16^3}}$$

Then, if you want, you can always arrange it better by writing

$$27 = 3^3 ~~~~~ 16 = 2^4$$

And have fun with exponents. Try!

Answer (score 1):

Since $27^{-2/3}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{27^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3^{3^2}}}=\frac{1}{3^2}=\frac{1}{9}$ and $16^{3/4}=\sqrt[4]{16^3}=\sqrt[4]{2^{4^3}}=2^3$ you have

$$\frac{1}{9}\times\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{72}$$